# Watch Pod containing several containers using kubernetes stream method

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers

I need to stream logs from a container inside a kubernetes pod. This was working well until I had just one container, but now with multiple containers in the same pod, I'm running into issues.

Kubernetes documentation seems inadequate for this problem, or maybe I have not looked enough yet.

Here's what I am trying to do:

Before (Works well):

```
w = watch.Watch()

for i in w.stream(api_instance.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=<pod_name>,
     namespace=<namespace>, tail_lines=<lines>):
    
    ...some code...
    ...some code...
```

With multiple containers, it throws error: ***a container name must be specified for pod***

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
w.stream(api_instance.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=pod_name, namespace=namespace, tail_lines=lines, container=<container_name>)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "I tried this but it doesn't work" -- did it result in a different error? Unexpected behavior? Freezing? Something else?

Comment: I have posted the error. Even after trying the fix - getting the same error